# JBOSS 6.1 WMQ Resource Adapter error

Tags: jboss, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to deploy a mdb configured with wmq.
Here the configuration:

```
@MessageDriven( name="WebSphereMQMDB", 
activationConfig =
{
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "SRVTEST"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1414"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "TEST.CHANNEL"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "Firco"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "username", propertyValue="admin"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "TestQueue")
})
@ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

But every 130 seconds I get this Stacktrace

```
14:58:45,337 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) WMQ Resource Adapter warning: MQJCA4003:A recoverable exception occurred in the JMS layer. See the linked exception for details.

14:58:45,337 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016009: Caught:: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.getXAResources(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:504)
at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryInflowImpl.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryInflowImpl.java:96)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jbossatx.jta.XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.java:51) [jbossjts-integration-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:516) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:182) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:743) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
at        com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371)     [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.15.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.15.Final-redhat-4]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you say what version of WMQ Resource Adapter you've deployed is please?

Comment: So i use JBOSS 6.1 EAP and i use wmq.jmsra.rar version j600-201 (build date 1/31/08) verion 6
Thank you

Comment: Would strong recommend you update the level of RA to something like the MQ 7.5; that version is now out of support.

Comment: Yes but where can i download it? I have one version MQ 8 but jboss 6.1 doesn't support it and I have the 6 ...

Comment: Follow this technote... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761

Don't worry about the references to Liberty - it's the same RA.

Comment: I download it and now I can't deploy it .
ERROR CommonServices has not been initialized.

Comment: Ok i found that my version was having problems ! I downloaded and I tried with the version 7.5.0.4-p750-004-140807
Everything works fine. Thank you!